# react-native update component, re-render view, on success automatically without state or props

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have this function

```
export function chooseContact(){

   ContactsWrapper.getContact().then((contact) => { //opens stock phone address book
    var phone = contact['phone']; // retrieves phone number from picked contact  
    global.phoneDemo = phone; //initializes to the global var in order to access from anywhere  

 }).catch((error) => { // these line standard 
    console.log("ERROR CODE: ", error.code);
    console.log("ERROR MESSAGE: ", error.message);

});}
```

After successfully storing phone number from contacts in a global var I am using it in my render view method

```
const Home = ({
  home
 value: {client},
onClientChange,
onSubmit}) => (

   <View style={styles.container}>
      <InputGroup borderType="underline" style={styles.inputGroup}>
  <Icon name="md-contact" style={styles.icon}/>

<Input value={global.phoneDemo?phoneDemo:client}
    onChangeText={onClientChange}/>
  <Icon name="ios-contacts" style={styles.addressBook} onPress=  {chooseContact}/> //this acceesses above function and opens stock contacts on a phone 
);
```

Everything is fine except one thing after storing the phone number in a global variable i am able to set it automatically on a input if i re-navigate to another component and return again, in that occasion only input fills automatically other ways no. How can i set it automatically after pick contact.

Comment: why do you insist on not using state ?

Comment: @HDevan oh I got a developed project already, seems like he was using react-redux

Comment: yeah @Amanda you still can update state through redux or the component state.

Comment: @HDevan can you show me the way ?

Comment: sorry I was away for some time. Is it still unresolved ?

Comment: @HDevan yeah still can't figure it out

Comment: @HDevan Hey are you there?